# How to rename a class member in an API-compatible manner?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, api-design, lifetime, backwards-compatibility

Given a fairly simple struct:

```
struct IMyClass {
    void (*f1)();
    void (*f2)();
    void (*f3)();
};
```

Is it possible to "rename" `IMyClass::f2` in an API-compatible manner? What I mean is giving the member another name, for example:

```
struct IMyClass {
    void (*f1)();
    union {
        void (*f2)();
        void (*f2_new)();
    };
    void (*f3)();
};
```

Would this be a valid and standards-compliant way to do it? I'm most concerned about whether the lifetimes of the non-static members of the union could hinder usage of both `f2` and `f2_new`.

Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: `API-compatible manner` and how does the api (what api?) use the members? What about just using an accessor? Are you aware that using non-active union member is undefined behavior?

Comment: @KamilCuk But what about the note in [class.union#2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.union#2)? Wouldn't it possible to somehow leverage the "common initial sequence" rules for this?

Comment: this is definitelly not language-lawyer question. I am struggling as well to get what you mean by API-compatible. Do you mean ABI or what?

Comment: @bartop No, I mean API. I could just plain rename it without any tricks for ABI-compatibility only. What I need is to keep old code like `myClass->f2()` working while also introducing means to use the function as `myClass->f2_new()` and keep the ABI (memory layout etc) the same as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your 'new' name for the function pointer a reference to the 'original'. The syntax for a "reference to a pointer to a function" is messy, so it's a lot clearer with a `typedef` or `using...` line beforehand:

```cpp
using pvf = void (*)();

struct IMyclass {
    pvf f1;
    pvf f2;
    pvf f3;
    pvf& f2_new = f2; // f2_new() will just 'redirect' to f2()
//  void (*&f2_new)() = f2; // The 'messy' way without using using.
};

void test1()
{
    std::cout << "test1" << std::endl;
}
void test2()
{
    std::cout << "test2" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    IMyclass imc;
    imc.f2 = test1;
    imc.f2_new();
    imc.f2 = test2;
    imc.f2_new();
    // Function (re-)assignment via the reference works, too...
    imc.f2_new = test1;
    imc.f2();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea. Nevertheless, will it also increase the size of `IMyClass`?

Comment: @jotik Yes, it will *probably* increase the size of your class (unless the new reference fits into any 'leftover' padding).

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any better alternatives?

Yes. It looks like you are reinventing virtual functions. Is there any reason not to use that instead?

That is, instead of:

```
struct IMyClass {
    void (*f1)();
    void (*f2)();
    void (*f3)();
};
```

why not use:

```
struct IMyClass {
    virtual void f1() = 0;
    virtual void f2() = 0;
    virtual void f3() = 0;
};
```

with a concrete implementation.

> What I need is to keep old code like myClass->f2() working while also introducing means to use the function as myClass->f2_new() and keep the ABI (memory layout etc) the same as well.

try implementing this instead:

```
struct specialized: public IMyClass 
{
    virtual void f2_new() = 0;
};
```

Comment: The reason not to use virtual functions is that switching over to virtual functions will break both API and ABI.